# Joint events - standard probability

Tags: probability

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are events with $P(A)=0.3$, $P(B)=0.4$ and $P(C)=0.5$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $A$ and $C$ are independent, and $P(B|C)=0.1$. Find $P(A \cup B \cup C)$.

I thought this could be solved by Inclusion-Exclusion. So:
\begin{align}
P(A \cup B \cup C) &= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
& = 0.3 + 0.4 + 0.5 - P(\emptyset) - P(A)P(C) - P(B|C)P(C) + P(\emptyset \cap C)\\
&= 1.2 - 0 - 0.3 \cdot 0.5 - 0.1 \cdot 0.5 + P(\emptyset) \\
&=1.2 - 0.15 - 0.05  \\
&=1.
\end{align}
Is this correct?!

Comment: I think it looks good.